# Converting if else condition to MIP constraints - validation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, big-m

I have an if else condition as follows: If $g \ge 0$ then $e=1$, else $e=b$.

I formulated MIP constraints using big-M as follows where I am setting $\delta=1$ if $g \ge 0$:

\begin{alignat}2g &\ge -M(1-\delta)\tag1\\g &\le M\delta\tag2\\1-M(1-\delta) &\le e \le 1+M(1-\delta)\tag3\\b-M\delta &\le e \le b+M\delta\tag4\end{alignat}

My question is if the formulation is correct, especially the first equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks correct, but there is the usual ambiguity at the boundary: $g=0$ allows either $e$ value.  Also, if $b$ is a constant, you can simplify by replacing (3) and (4) with a single equality:
$$e=1\delta+b(1-\delta)$$
Note that the best values of $M$ in (3) and (4) yield this equality.  Explicitly:
\begin{align}
1-(1-b)(1-\delta) &\le e \le 1+(b-1)(1-\delta) \tag3\\
b-(b-1)\delta &\le e \le b+(1-b)\delta &&\tag4
\end{align}

Comment: Follow up question, if g is a parameter with set of values in this case, does big M formulation apply? If not, what can be done to convert the if else to constraints ?

Comment: By "parameter" do you mean a decision variable or a constant?

Comment: Constant (a set of constant values), not a decision variable. Also, b is a single constant.

Comment: If $g$ and $b$ are constants, you do not need to introduce $\delta$, impose big-M constraints, or call any solver. 
 The value of $e$ is already completely determined once you know $g$ and $b$.